# Inheriting classes and namespaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

What I want to do now is to make changements in FUNC.cpp and FUNC.h to inherit it to main.cpp and then, **generate a diagram class** at the end in which is really states that FUNC is inherited.

I want to make changements in my code, from namespace to classes, to allow the inheritance process.

I ' m having what is follow:

In a FUNC.h:

```
   namespace FUNC
{
    void f1(...);
    void f2(...);
}
```

In a FUNC.cpp

```
namespace FUNC
{

    void f1(...)
    {

    }

    void f2(...)
    {

    }

}
```

in test.cpp (which is meantime a class an having its test.h) , it's possible to call f1 and f2 as follow:

```
FUNC::f1(...);
FUNC::f2(...);
```

Comment: I don't know what it is that you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit"? You can't inherit namespaces.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited my question, you can see above. I do know that namespaces cannot be inherited. And I have to deal with inheritance notions. The idea is to make changements from a namespace to a class to allow inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the namespace to a class, but still want to call `func1` and `func2` using the same syntax (e.g. `FUNC::func1()`), you have to make the functions `static`:

```
struct FUNC
{
    static void func1();
    static void func2();
};
```

---

If you want to override `func1` in an inherited class then it's simple:

```
struct FUNC2 : public FUNC
{
    static void func1();
};
```

There are however problems with static member functions, in that they can't access non-static members easily.

Comment: That's a good start of my question answer. Thanks .
The second part of my question, is to generate a diagram class of my project. I would like to inherit FUNC : public main. How is it possible to do so?

Comment: @MelMed I'm not sure I follow what you want to do. What do you mean by "generating a diagram class"? If you want to generate a class diagram to e.g. print then check out e.g. [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/). I also don't know what you mean when you want to inherit "FUNC : public main"? There's only one `main` global function, it can never be inside a class or namespace in C++.

Comment: I ' m having main.cpp / main.h CLASS (not the default main program) and I also want to have that FUNC which is inherited from MAIN class, to generate a class diagram with Vs2010.

Comment: There is no class main usually. You can generate diagrams in VS by clicking buttons, rather than running code to do it. Right click on the project and select view class diagram

Comment: @doctorlove I want to establish classes. I was using namespaces but if they really were classes, 
I shall call then main another name: test.cpp / test.h

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question

I had to insert after

```
class FUNC: public TEST
{
    static void func1();
    static void func2();
};
```